# How to connect to Google Cloud Platform Data Storage from Google Cloud AI Jupyter Notebook(Python)?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I need to save/read a file from this location -

```
bucket name - 'bucket_name'
folder - 'user/test'
```

I need to know how to connect to this location & read/write files.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-run-a-notebook-for-data-science-on-google-cloud-with-a-database-and-a-gpu-in-15min-f662f36c3a66) is a complete tutorial for how to read a file from your Cloud Storage in your AI Jupyter Notebook

And you can also follow this step by step [tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=write+data+to+cloud+storage+from+ai+notebook&rlz=1CAQUPU_enES880&oq=write+data+to+cloud+storage+from+ai+notebook&aqs=chrome..69i57.11254j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to read/Write files.

```
import google.datalab.storage as storage
import pandas as pd from io
import BytesIO

def get_bucket(bucket_target):
    shared_bucket = storage.Bucket(str(bucket_name))
   return shared_bucket

def read_file_from_bucket(file_target):
    shared_bucket = get_bucket(bucket_target)
    sample_object = shared_bucket.object(str(file_target)
    sample_text = sample_object.read_stream()
    return sample_text
```

Or you can do this :

```
import tensorflow as tf

GCS_PATTERN = 'gs://my_bucket/folder/*.tfrec'
filenames = tf.gfile.Glob(GCS_PATTERN)
```